# DRF Serializer not displaying fields (Foreign Key and many2many) in default HTML form page API. Field is available in GET

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-serializer

DRF Serializer contains a group and inventory field which are many2many and foreign key. It is missing in default DRF HTML Form but available in GET view. currently, the depth field is enabled in Serializer. If i am removing depth then Foreign key is available in default HTML form, but still group many2many field is missing. I need both the fields for POST call or in DRF HTML Form.

Do i have to write some create method, but I do not want to create new record for Foreign key and many2many just want to utilize the existing field.

My Serializer class.

```
class MainHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainHost
        fields = (
            'host_id', 
            'host_name',
            'inventory',
            'group'
        )  
        # depth = 2
```

Raw view for default DRF HTML Form

```
{
    "host_id": null,
    "host_name": ""
}
```

Model Class

```
class MainHost(models.Model):
    host_id =  models.IntegerField(verbose_name='HOST ID', primary_key=True)
    host_name =  models.CharField(verbose_name='HOST NAME', max_length=512)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(related_name='inv_ins', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to='hosts.MainInventory', blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(MainGroup, related_name='hostgroups', through ='HostGroup')
```

Comment: I am able to see the Many2Many field in DRF POST Html Form by adding the create method. But while submitting POST form is not adding a record for group(many2many) field  in MainHost

Comment: Create Response  HTTP 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "host_id": 555555,
    "host_name": "tes",
    "inventory": 13,
    "group": [],
    "description": "test"
}

Comment: class MainHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=HostGroup.objects.all(), many=True)
   
    def create(self, validated_data):
        #hostgroup_data = validated_data.pop('hostgroup')
        group = validated_data.pop('group')
        host = MainHost.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return host
    class Meta:
        model = MainHost
        fields = (
            'host_id', 
            'host_name',
            'inventory',
            'group'
        )

Comment: How will POST submit work with group many2many field? currently its adding empty record

Comment: How will I insert records in Many2Many model HostGroup?

Comment: using a similar approach: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164616/django-rest-framework-manytomany-relationship-through-intermediate-model

Comment: Similar to this but for Many2Many field, it did not work.     def create(self, validated_data):
      group = validated_data.pop('group')
        print(group)
        instance = MainHost.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print(instance)

        for eachgrp in group:
            HostGroup.objects.create(**eachgrp, group=instance)
        return instance

Answer (score 0):

Create Method for MainHost Serializer

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    inv_data = validated_data.pop('inventory')
    inv_res = MainInventory.objects.create(**inv_data)

    group_data = validated_data.pop('group')
    host_data = MainHost.objects.create(inventory = inv_res, **validated_data)

    for g_data in group_data:
        inv_data = g_data.pop('inv_id')
        inv = MainInventory.objects.create(**inv_data)
        group_res = MainGroup.objects.create(inv_id = inv, **g_data)
        print(validated_data)
        HostGroup.objects.create(host = host_data, group =  group_res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was sample JSON

```
{
    "count": 1692,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/mainhost/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "host_id": 4087,
            "host_name": "10.240.144.2",
            "inventory": {
                "inv_id": 91,
                "inv_name": "GNS Switches (TestNet)",
                "total_hosts": 539,
                "total_groups": 1,
                "org_name": "ABC_TestNet",
                "description": "Inventory of ABC switches on Testnet",
                "inv_variables": "environ: testnet"
            },
            "group": [
                {
                    "group_id": 280,
                    "group_name": "aruba",
                    "total_hosts": 539,
                    "total_groups": 0,
                    "inv_id": {
                        "inv_id": 91,
                        "inv_name": "ABC Switches (TestNet)",
                        "total_hosts": 539,
                        "total_groups": 1,
                        "org_name": "ABC_TestNet",
                        "description": "Inventory of ABC switches on Testnet",
                        "inv_variables": "environ: testnet"
                    },
                    "description": "imported",
                    "group_variables": "{}",
                    "groupinv_name": "ABC Switches (TestNet)",
                    "groupinv_description": "",
                    "groupinv_source": "scm",
                    "groupinv_path": "TEC/GNS/Switches/testnet.ini"
                }
            ],
            "description": "imported",
            "foreman_group": "[{'id': 280, 'name': 'aruba'}]",
            "host_variables": "{}",
            "ansible_facts": "{}"
        }
    ]
}
```